# How to retrigger a function if it doesn't work the first time?

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have an image/media tumblr which loads 12-25 images on the first page, which have the potential to be quite large.

I have jQuery doing various cosmetic things to the layout and images, in particular, I'm checking each post to see if it is a photoset, which is served as an iframe by Tumblr.

Visually, one sees a gallery of thumbnail previews of the photoset, when you click on a thumbnail, it opens a lightbox slideshow with the full size photo.

My tweek waits for the iframe to load, removes the thumbnail gallery and replaces it with the first full resolution image in the gallery.

Here is my code:

```
$(".post_relative").each(function () {
        var post_relative = $(this);
        var photoset = post_relative.find('.html_photoset');
        if(photoset.length){
            var myFrame = photoset.find("iframe");
            myFrame.load(function(){
                console.log("frame loaded");
                var newCover = myFrame.contents().find('.photoset').children(':first-child').children(':first-child');
                myFrame.contents().find('img').each(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                })
                newCover.children(':first-child').remove();
                var psPre = newCover.attr("href")+ '?' + (Math.random() * 1000000);
                newCover.append("<img src='"+ psPre +"' alt='Cover Page' />");
                var psHeight = newCover.find('img');
                psHeight.load(function(){
                if (psHeight.height()>heightRef){
                    psHeight.height(heightRef);
                }
                newCover.detach();
                post_relative.append(newCover);
                myFrame.hide();
            })
            })
        }
```

Anyway, it works, 75% of the time. I can only imagine that Tumblr is sometimes overloaded, or maybe there is too much going on on the page?

What causes jQuery to be inconsistent? Is there jQuery code that allows me to double check that the code completed correctly?

You can see it work or not work here:
http://syndex.me

If it's not working, the third post will look like this:
[image: wrong]

If it works correctly it will look like this:
[image: right]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the piece of that code that intermittently works may be your `load` handler on the `iframe`.  If the iframe is not loaded due to the browser cache or if there is a race condition where the frame has already loaded before your load handler was attached, then your handler may not be triggered.

**Update**

Evan's answer is spot on and probably the right one; you should have error handling for your load handler.  If, however, you find out that the frame loading isn't erroring out, but rather that your handler isn't being triggered:

1. If this is due to a race condition, make sure you redesign your code so you attach event handlers before inserting the frames into the DOM.
2. If this is due to caching, affix something to the frames' URLs to ensure they're always unique.

Comment: I was guessing it might be that part of the code. How can I make that more solid though? Perhaps through Evan's answer?

Comment: @Evan's answer is great because you also need error handling for iframe loading.  In fact, maybe that's your only problem.  If you determine that a frame loads without errors and without triggering your handler, then my answer is more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can try two things. First thing I would do is add a callback to your load function:

```
myFrame.load("yourUrl", function(response, status, xhr) {
  if (status == "error") {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";

    // do whatever if there is an error

    $("#error").html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

If this doesn't work for you I would recommend a [try catch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp) statement in your code. Wrap the try around the block of code you think is failing and then add a catch statement so you will know if you come across an error in that particular block. you can also [throw custom errors](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/) to give you an idea what exactly failed.

Comment: I've never seen the ajax signature of .load used with an iframe... Does that produce the same results as changing the src attribute of the iframe element? Will it work with x-domain urls such as tumblr?

Comment: I'll take a look at this later today and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I've added try and catch in every line of the code, but get no console logs, am i doing something wrong? Surely that would find the culprit. http://marckremers.com/syndex/js/private.js

Comment: that isn't quite how you are supposed to do use try catch, and I'm guessing having so many is the reason its not working. what happens if you just leave that first one in there with the alllert, does it work on its own?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the try/catch is just to see if there are any formatting errors in your code. It catches the 'alllert' bug each time, but when the code for the iframe refromatting doesn't work as it should, it shows no catches at all.